# Refreshing Gui on solo thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, repaint, paintcomponent

iam coding one app and i want to draw some marks and pictures over the map.But here i have the problem.When i push button iam starting the thread with 30 miliseconds delay.But in fact it looks like this task is running on main thread cause the gui stop refreshing and cant do anything with it.
Heres my code

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MapDrawer extends JPanel
{
     Graphics testGrafika;
     DrawerThread drawingThread;

    public MapDrawer(JPanel drawPanel)
    {
        drawPanel.add(this);
        testGrafika=drawPanel.getGraphics();    
        paintComponent(testGrafika);
        drawingThread=new DrawerThread();
        drawingThread.run();            
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(10, 25, 200, 200);
    }

    public Graphics getGraphics()
    {
        return testGrafika;         
    }

    public class DrawerThread extends Thread implements Runnable
    {   
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                repaint();
                try {
                    DrawerThread.sleep(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my GUI class:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import org.eclipse.wb.swing.FocusTraversalOnArray;

import soft.MapDrawer;
import soft.MapView;

import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;

public class MainWindow {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JMenu MenuBasicActions;
    private JInternalFrame mapFrameRef;
    private JPanel drawPanelRef;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()

        {
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MainWindow()
    {
        initialize();               
    }

    public JFrame getMainFrame()
    {
        return frame;
    }

    public JPanel getDrawPanel()
    {
        return drawPanelRef;    
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1024, 768);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);           

        JMenuBar menuBarUpper = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBarUpper);

        MenuBasicActions = new JMenu("GPS Settings");
        menuBarUpper.add(MenuBasicActions);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
        MenuBasicActions.add(mntmNewMenuItem);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem_1 = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
        MenuBasicActions.add(mntmNewMenuItem_1);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem_2 = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
        MenuBasicActions.add(mntmNewMenuItem_2);

        JMenu DevicesMenu = new JMenu("Devices");
        menuBarUpper.add(DevicesMenu);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem_3 = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
        DevicesMenu.add(mntmNewMenuItem_3);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem_4 = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
        DevicesMenu.add(mntmNewMenuItem_4);

        JMenu HelpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBarUpper.add(HelpMenu); 

        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
        frame.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                paint();
            }
        });
        toolBar.add(btnNewButton_1);


        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        toolBar.add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("New button");
        toolBar.add(btnNewButton_2);

        JButton btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("New button");
        toolBar.add(btnNewButton_3);
        toolBar.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{btnNewButton_1, btnNewButton}));

        JInternalFrame mapFrame = new JInternalFrame("Military Tracking System");
        mapFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mapFrame, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mapFrame.setVisible(true);

        JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel();
        drawPanel.setOpaque(false);
        mapFrame.setGlassPane(drawPanel);
        drawPanel.setVisible(true);

        drawPanel.setBorder(null);
        //mapFrame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{frame.getContentPane(), toolBar, btnNewButton_1, btnNewButton, btnNewButton_2, btnNewButton_3, menuBarUpper, MenuBasicActions, mntmNewMenuItem, mntmNewMenuItem_1, mntmNewMenuItem_2, DevicesMenu, mntmNewMenuItem_3, mntmNewMenuItem_4, HelpMenu}));

        MapView hlavnaMapa=new MapView();
        hlavnaMapa.Init(mapFrame);  
        mapFrameRef=mapFrame;
        drawPanelRef=drawPanel;
    }

    public void paint()
    {
        MapDrawer drawer=new MapDrawer(drawPanelRef);
        //drawer.paintComponent(drawer.getGraphics());          
    }
}
```

What i want to do is running gui on one thread and draw objects on other,so i can control gui.

Answer (score 1):

In order to start the `Thread` you should invoke `drawingThread.start();` instead of `run()`.

[`start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) will then start a new thread and call the method `run()` inside this thread. If you instead call `run()` it will run on the same thread as the caller.